# "yarn hardhat run scripts/propose.ts --network localhost" - Console.log not working?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, hardhat-deploy

Can anyone spot some an issue that may be preventing my console.log to work in this file i have created in my script folder?

What i am doing is first opening terminal #1, and running ***npx hardhat node***. This compiles my contracts successfully and creates 10 acccounts on the hardhat localhost.

Then i open terminal #2 and do... ***yarn hardhat run scripts/propose.ts --network localhost*** This returns Done is whatever seconds, but it is not showing any of the console.log statements i set up in the file? I don't think the issue is what I am trying to console.log, because even when it was somehing very simple it would not return it. It seems to be something else?  Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Propose function inside the propose function.. so it does not call any function while you running your script..

Propose.then.catch should be outside the function, so it can be executed at runtime..

Comment: You were right! Problem solved. Thank you!